# How to handle input arugments to Batch file?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-file

I'm trying to handle an input argument when I do call script.bat argument
If argument is missing, the receiving script.bat will pop a prompt to ask user to assign value. But right now even if I do script.bat number, the prompt shows up anyway...not sure why.

**Code:**

```
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Prompt
  set VAR=%1
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Prompt
  set /p VAR="Check which value? "
  GOTO Continue
:Continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip the `:Prompt` if the argument was supplied correctly:

```
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Prompt
  SET VAR=%1
  GOTO Continue
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Prompt
  set /p VAR="Check which value? "
  GOTO Continue
:Continue
```

Actually, you can now remove the `SHIFT` and `GOTO Loop`; as @dbenham posted in the comment below, it's unreachable code. This also eliminates the `:Loop` itself, as it is never used. This reduces it to:

```
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Prompt
  SET VAR=%1
  GOTO Continue
:Prompt
  set /p VAR="Check which value? "
  GOTO Continue
:Continue
```

Comment: Why keep `SHIFT` or `GOTO Loop`? - they are dead code that can never execute with this logic.

Comment: @dbenham: The question didn't ask how to optimize the batch file or reduce the number of lines of code. It asked a specific question, which I answered; I didn't take the time to do a code review. ;-) I edited to provide an improved version, with proper credit given.

Answer (score 0):

If %1 is set, you have to go to your continue label.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted Ken White solution will work, but it can be greatly simplified.

```
set "VAR=%~1"
if not defined VAR set /p "VAR=Check which value? "
```

The user could simply press `<Enter>` without entering anything. You could introduce a GOTO loop to enforce entry of a value.

```
set "VAR=%~1"
:loop
if not defined VAR set /p "VAR=Check which value? "&goto :loop
```